# Threads - running even if main app hangs?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, concurrency, parallel-processing

Is it possible to have running thread in C# app, which do some task in a loop, even if main gui process is totally deadlocked, hang, and form is unable to be refreshed, looks like frozen, no reaction to user?

Is it posible to have running and correctly working thread in such app state or only way is another process?

Windows, c# winform app.

.NET FRAMEWORK 3.5 (not higher)

Comment: Yes, for a short period of time anyway. If the app is hung Windows will realize that it isn't processing the message pump and mark the process as "hung" and ask you to terminate it.

Comment: Why would the main app "hang" in the first place? Isn't one of the the ideas of asynchronous programming to stop the GUI hanging?

Comment: You can even do tasks in a loop and have the GUI deadlocked/frozen *without* using different threads! Smells like an XY problem to me.

Comment: I need it for testing and learning purpose. Lets say main app has timer, this timer checks hardware device which can return after minute or hang deadlocking indefinitely without returning state (i know instead of timer there should be thread but i want to test it with timer for learning purpose), and even if this main app timer hangs (and timer is running in gui process) mine thread would work anyway, like writing to log etc?

Comment: @itsme86 how i can do that?

Comment: ok, but if main app is reading from disk, some bytes files, and another thread is doing something different, and there is hardware error like bad sector, this second thread will really still run and do what i told to do?

Comment: No. If you kill the process, all the threads associated with that process die with it. You said the GUI was hung/frozen. Not killed. That's *completely* different.

Comment: i am not going to kill. I wrote it to tell how much hanged this process is, even task manager can not kill it, will my second thread still run in such hanged process?

Comment: Yes, threads run independently of each other. If one is frozen, others will keep going.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167882/discussion-between-user2265690-and-itsme86).

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Reading the question, it almost looks like you intentionally want the main thread to hang, and you also want your applicable to be unkillable through task manager.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. That is whole purpose of threads: continue independent execution while other parts might be in hang/wait state or do something different.

But, as it was mentioned in comments, in `UI` applications, the notion of freezed UI, while other thread is working on something defeats the purpose of `UI` itself, as a meta to the user, which is supposed to be responsive and pleasant to interact with.

Comment: ok, so if i have in main gui app thread procedure to read from disk, but this disk has bad sector and sometimes i can not kill this hanged process even in task manaer, smple Thread will still work and run in code i written ?

Comment: No. If you kill the process, all the threads associated with that process die with it. You said the GUI was hung/frozen. Not killed. That's *completely* different.

Comment: @user2265690: threads are "children" of process and their lifetime is bound by the lifetime of process itself.

Comment: i am not going to kill it, i wrote that it is impossible to kill it in task manager to tell how much hanged this process is.